# Serializing into Xml document

Tags: c#

I am trying to serialize this class that will display this in an xml document.

```
<InventoryType>
    <Date>20160925</Date>
    <HotelId>123</HotelId>
    <RoomType>KB</RoomType>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
</InventoryType>
<InventoryType>
    <Date>20160901</Date>
    <HotelId>123</HotelId>
    <RoomType>QB</RoomType>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
</InventoryType>
```

I have a list, and i want to iterate through it, and insert the 3 dates. like above. but i cant figure how to do it. i know i need a forloop for the datetime. but do i need another inner for loop for the list as well?

```
public void CreateInvenList()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2016,09,28);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2016, 09, 25);

    List<InventoryType> Inventoryttype = new List<InventoryType>();
    Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(start, "123", "KB", num));
    Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(start, "124", "qB", num));

    for ( DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddDays(1) )
    {
        for (??)
        {
            // what goes in here? 
        }
    }

    serial = new XmlSerializer(Inventoryttype.GetType()); 
    sw = new StreamWriter(Inventory_Filename);
    serial.Serialize(sw, Inventoryttype);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: for (var inventory in Inventoryttype)? I don't really get what you're trying to do though. If you want to add all dates in all objects in list than that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need another loop as you assign a value for each day

```
for ( DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddDays(1) )
{
    num = rnd.Next();
    Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, "123", "KB", num));
    Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, "124", "qB", num));
}
```

That will work if you want to add only those room/hotel types for the given days. However if you have a datasource with hotels and rooms, then you will need to add an inner loop to change hotels, if the room types change per hotels then you should add another inner loop for the rooms.

If you have a datasource with multiple hotels but have 'KB' and 'QB' as common room types among all hotels your code should look like this:

```
for ( DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddDays(1) )
{
    foreach (var hotel in hotels)
    {
        num = rnd.Next();
        Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, hotel.id, "KB", num));
        Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, hotel.id, "QB", num));
    )
}
```

And in the case that you would have specific room types for each hotels and number of rooms per default for the room types you can have that:

```
for ( DateTime date = start; date < end; date = date.AddDays(1) )
{
    foreach (var hotel in hotels)
    {
        foreach (var roomType in hotels.roomTypes)
        {
            num = rnd.Next();
            Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, hotel.id, roomType.id, num));
        }
    )
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes that that helps a lot.   the problem im having now is the             Random rnd = new Random();    is giving me the same number for all of them .   which is num in the ` Inventoryttype.Add(new InventoryType(date, hotel.id, roomType.id, **num**));`

Comment: If you want the random to change all the time you should put it in the same loop as the one you add the inventorytype objects. Updating my reply.

Comment: Ah k. got it. Yea it is changing now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @user6875449 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.